# TAO Notify service can't start in suse

Tags: ace, tao

Recently I built a ace tao in suse with the official documents successfully, and the Naming service run ok, but when I started Notify service, An error was occurred, 
I started the service by following way,

```
$TAO_ROOT/orbsvcs/Naming Service/Naming_service
$TAO_ROOT/orbsvcs/Notify Service/Notify_service
```

error information:

> Using 1 threads for each ConsumerAdmin. pure virtual method called
>   terminate called without an active exception Aborted (core dumped)

ACE and TAO version is 6.1.0, anybody who can help me?

Comment: This TAO version is ancient, please upgrade to TAO 6.4.0

Comment: What is the stack trace of the crash?